# Facing an error while assigning values to a list

Tags: java, list

I have a list which has 3 elements. It is in a while loop and I want to overwrite its values in each iterations. Here is the code:

```
private List<Integer> loadList = new ArrayList<>(3);
.
.
.
while(counter < 10) {
    loadList.add(0, taskNum);
    loadList.add(1, taskNum);
    loadList.add(2, taskNum);
    .
    .
    .
    counter++;
}
```

But after running the code I realized that overwriting is not happening and each time the new elements are being added to the end of the list. For example:

> At first : a = [1 2 3]
>
> Then: a = [1 2 3 4 5 6] but I want it to be like a = [4 5 6]

So I changed my code to something like this:

```
loadList = new ArrayList<>(3);
//initializing
loadList.add(0, 0);
loadList.add(1, 0);
loadList.add(2, 0);
while(counter < 10) {
    loadList.set(0, taskNum);
    loadList.set(1, taskNum);
    loadList.set(2, taskNum);
    .
    .
    .
    counter++;
}
```

But now I'm getting this error:

```
2018-11-24 13:27:38.298 ERROR [n.f.core.Main] Exception in main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:448) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at net.floodlightcontroller.mactracker.Mactracker.paramInit(Mactracker.java:137) ~[floodlight.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at net.floodlightcontroller.mactracker.Mactracker.init(Mactracker.java:205) ~[floodlight.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at net.floodlightcontroller.core.module.FloodlightModuleLoader.initModules(FloodlightModuleLoader.java:460) ~[floodlight.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at net.floodlightcontroller.core.module.FloodlightModuleLoader.loadModulesFromList(FloodlightModuleLoader.java:295) ~[floodlight.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at net.floodlightcontroller.core.module.FloodlightModuleLoader.loadModulesFromConfig(FloodlightModuleLoader.java:235) ~[floodlight.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at net.floodlightcontroller.core.Main.main(Main.java:61) ~[floodlight.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
```

What's wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: BTW, what is taskNum, how are the values getting set to it?

Comment: The value of taskNum is variable and is changing in another part of the code. I thought it is not necessary to mention the way its value is changing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this line:

```
loadList = new ArrayList<>(3);
```

you defined that the **initial** capacity of the list is 3.
Now you can add as many items as you want not only 3.  
But still your list is empty. 
You cannot use:

```
loadList.set(2, taskNum);
```

if there is no item in the 3d position.  
`set(position, item)` is valid only if there is already an item at `position`.  
So use `add(item)` to add new items at the end of the list 
and `set(position, item)` to replace the item that is already in the list at `position`.  
You can also use `add(position, item)` to insert a new item at `position`, and shift the items from this `position` to the right.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as you are trying to set value at an index which is greater than the size of the list.

```
loadList.add(0, 0);
loadList.add(1, 0);
loadList.set(2, 0); <--------------- You will get IndexOutOfBound here
```

As `List#set` method throws an exception when if the index is out of range`(index < 0 || index > size()`. Use `loadList.add(2, 0)`, instead of `loadList.set(2, 0);` will solve your issue.

Comment: In other words, that last `set` should _also_ have been an `add`, just like the first two...

Answer (score 1):

When you initializing like this,

```
loadList.add(0, 0);
loadList.add(1, 0);
loadList.set(2, 0); <--- here you are setting instead of adding the value :)
```

It should be changed to,

```
loadList.add(0, 0);
loadList.add(1, 0);
loadList.add(2, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you set the object at the particular index which is not defined yet.

```
loadList = new ArrayList<>(3); menas your arryList have initial capacity 3.
```

first you have to add element at positions then set the elements. try this

```
loadList.add(0, 0);
loadList.add(1, 0);
loadList.add(2, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

An Example, That will give you an Idea.

```
List alist = new ArrayList();
    alist.add("1");
    alist.add("2");
    alist.add("3");
    int j=4;
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
        System.out.println("alist.get(0)"+alist.get(0));
        System.out.println("alist.get(1)"+alist.get(1));
        System.out.println("alist.get(2)"+alist.get(2)+"\n");
        alist.add(0, j++);
        alist.add(1, j++);
        alist.add(2, j++);
    }
```